# why the web browser is not setting the cookie?

Tags: go, cookies, axios

I have the following scenario:

- A REST API application running on api.company.com
- A frontend application running on frontend.company.com that makes requests to api.company.com for getting resources to display in the frontend.

I'm setting a cookie in a call and it seems to work properly on postman.
The relevant part of the code where I set the cookie is the following one (in GO):

```
expire := time.Now().Add(24 * time.Hour)
cookie := http.Cookie{
    Name:    "Token",
    Value:   "value",
    Expires: expire,
    Domain: "company.com",
}
http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)
w.Write([]byte("The response")
```

Once I've tried with postman and saw that the backend was working as expected and was sending the cookie I also made the request in the frontend using the `axios` library.
The relevant part in the code:

```
http.post(resource, {
    field1,
    field2
}, 
{
    withCredentials: true,
    cancelToken: cancelToken.token,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'token',
    },
```

})

I get the answer as expected, "The response" string,  but the cookie is not set bt the web browser.
Opening the Chrome console and going to the Network tab I can see that the cookie is sent by the backend but for some reason is refused by the web browser.
I think is not related to the domain since is company.com nor by the expiration, since is set for tomorrow.
The headers in the response are the following:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Token, NewToken
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 280
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 10 Dec 2019 13:12:06 GMT
Set-Cookie: Token="value value"; Domain=api.company.com; Expires=Wed, 11 Dec 2019 13:12:06 GMT
Status: 200
Vary: Origin
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Deliberately set the Path of the Cookie. 2. Make sure you are allowed to set a domain cookie: Domain cookies are simply ignored if not made properly, e.g. If your Server run under a different name than "company.com".

Comment: 1a. The path is usually set to "/".